# Smtp mail Send error php

Tags: email, php

I am try to send mail through smtp server(gmail) from my localhost(wamp).When running the program it  will display the **Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded** .I was change the timeout gain it will produce same error

```
<?php
$to = "email@gmail.com";
$nameto = "Who To";
$from = "from@fast2host.com";
$namefrom = "Who From";
$subject = "Hello World Again!";
$message = "World, Hello!";
authSendEmail($from, $namefrom, $to, $nameto, $subject, $message);

function authSendEmail($from, $namefrom, $to, $nameto, $subject, $message)
{
//SMTP + SERVER DETAILS
/* * * * CONFIGURATION START * * * */
$smtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com";
$port = "25";
$timeout = "30";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$localhost = "27.107.106.163";
$newLine = "\r\n";
/* * * * CONFIGURATION END * * * * */

//Connect to the host on the specified port
$smtpConnect = fsockopen($smtpServer, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout);
$smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);
if(empty($smtpConnect))
{
$output = "Failed to connect: $smtpResponse";
return $output;
}
else
{
$logArray['connection'] = "Connected: $smtpResponse";
}

//Request Auth Login
fputs($smtpConnect,"AUTH LOGIN" . $newLine);
$smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);
$logArray['authrequest'] = "$smtpResponse";

//Send username
fputs($smtpConnect, base64_encode($username) . $newLine);
$smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);
$logArray['authusername'] = "$smtpResponse";

//Send password
fputs($smtpConnect, base64_encode($password) . $newLine);
$smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);
$logArray['authpassword'] = "$smtpResponse";

//Say Hello to SMTP
fputs($smtpConnect, "HELO $localhost" . $newLine);
$smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);
$logArray['heloresponse'] = "$smtpResponse";

//Email From
fputs($smtpConnect, "MAIL FROM: $from" . $newLine);
$smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);
$logArray['mailfromresponse'] = "$smtpResponse";

//Email To
fputs($smtpConnect, "RCPT TO: $to" . $newLine);
$smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);
$logArray['mailtoresponse'] = "$smtpResponse";

//The Email
fputs($smtpConnect, "DATA" . $newLine);
$smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);
$logArray['data1response'] = "$smtpResponse";

//Construct Headers
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $newLine;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . $newLine;
$headers .= "To: $nameto <$to>" . $newLine;
$headers .= "From: $namefrom <$from>" . $newLine;

fputs($smtpConnect, "To: $to\nFrom: $from\nSubject: $subject\n$headers\n\n$message        \n.\n");
$smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);
$logArray['data2response'] = "$smtpResponse";

// Say Bye to SMTP
fputs($smtpConnect,"QUIT" . $newLine);
$smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);
$logArray['quitresponse'] = "$smtpResponse";
}
?>
```

Please help me anyone for debug the errors

Comment: Pretty obvious... whatever server you're trying to connect to hasn't been reachable within the PHP timeout of 30 seconds, so the script's killed. Your internal timeout is 100 seconds, and PHP's timing out in 30, so you never see your own error.

Comment: SMTP servers can be nasty. What happens if you just run `fclose` after the `QUIT` instead of that final `fgets`?

Comment: Are you really intending to establish an SSL connection? I see no certificate setup, just plain fsockopen. Port 465 is for SMTP over SSL only; you want either 25 for plain SMTP or 587 for Mail Submission.

Comment: @konrad: you can still open an ssl port without doing any of the ssl stuff. Problem is that the OP isn't actually SENDING anything to the server, and SMTP servers won't start talking until you do, so the connection's just sitting there, idle.

Comment: Please kindly mention how to edit the code...

Comment: Try using an already built library for sending mail such as [phpMailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/) or [Pear Mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail) instead of trying to talk directly to the SMTP server yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You have too much redundant code, this is what you should do:

```
<?php
    require_once 'Mail.php';
    require_once 'Mail/mime.php';
    // set all of the parameters
    $to = "Who To <email@gmail.com>";
    $from = "Who From <from@fast2host.com>";
    $subject = "Hello World Again!";
    $message = "World, Hello!";

    $text = strip_tags($message);

    // create the headers
    $headers = array(
        'Subject' => $subject,
        'From' => $from,
        'To' => $to,
        'MIME-Version' => '1.0',
        'Date' => date('r'),
        'Message-ID' => '<'.sha1(microtime(true)).'@mydomain.com>',
        'Content-Type' => 'text/html',
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => 'quoted-printable',
    ); // end $headers


    // create the message
    $mime = new Mail_mime("\n");
    $mime->setTXTBody($text);
    $mime->setHTMLBody($message);

    // always call these methods in this order
    $body = $mime->get();
    $headers = $mime->headers($headers);

    // create the smtp mail object
    $smtp_params = array(
        'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => 'myUserName',
        'password' => 'myPassWord',
    ); // end $smtp_params
    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', $smtp_params);

    // send the message

    $recipients = array($to);
    $mail = $smtp->send($recipients, $headers, $body);

?>
```

PS. The 'auth'=> true; in the smtp_params array flags for an ssl connection.